# Inequality in probability theory.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let X be a nonnegative random variable and let $(\mathcal{H}_i)$ be a sequence of increasing $\sigma$ algebras. Let $(A_i)_{0 \leqslant i \leqslant N}$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint events. Do we have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^N \mathbb{E} \big( \mathbb{1}_{A_i} \mathbb{E}\big(X | \mathcal{H}_i \big) \big) \leqslant \mathbb{E}(X) ? $$

Comment: No, otherwise, it will be obvious.

Comment: No, there is no relashionship between the events $A_{i}$ and the $\sigma$ algebras $H_{i}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\Omega=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, let $H_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ and let $H_1$ be the $\sigma$-field  generated by $X={\bf 1}_{[0,1/2]}$  (or we could take $H_1$ to be the full Lebesgue $\sigma$-field.)
Then  $$ {\bf 1}_{( 1/2,1]}E(X|H_0)=\frac12 \cdot {\bf 1}_{( 1/2,1]} \quad \text{a.e.} $$  and
$$ {\bf 1}_{[0,1/2 ]}E(X|H_1)=   {\bf 1}_{[0,1/2 ]}\quad \text{a.e.} $$
Adding the expectations of the two displays yields $1/4+1/2>E(X)$.

Comment: Okey i see, thanks very much.